# Comparing empty string column with a non empty string column give me True for all the values that do not match

Tags: python, pandas, validation

I was trying this function but give me true for all the values that are supposed to be False.

Columns:

```
column of df

 status
activate
activate
activate
disabled
activate
disabled
activate
disabled
activate
```

The columns of `df1` contain just `nan strings` and I applied `(df1['status'].str.lower().isin([x.lower() for x in df['status']])`

```
df1:
status
 nan
 nan
 nan
 nan
 nan
 nan

Result:
True
True
True
True
True
True
```

The length of the columns are not the same but it does not matter. I wonder know why is giving me `True` for the values that do not match. Anyone can help or knows something about it?. What am I doing wrong?. I hope someone can answer this time.

Comment: Please include an example of the desired output.  This will help clarify your question and help you get a response.

Comment: @jezrael I think it will be false because the values in status of df1 and df do not match. In one place is an empty column and in the other have values.

Comment: Sorry, I think you test same columns, not idea.

Comment: @jezrael do you have any idea how to solve this?